# How to make such a table in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, templates

All good day.

Tell me how to map such a thing in bootstrap:

[codepen.io/anon/pen/bqJdQJ](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqJdQJ)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="http://my.ln-family.com/image/banners/ban111.jpg" class="img-responsive">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <img src="http://my.ln-family.com/image/banners/ban22.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <img src="http://my.ln-family.com/image/banners/ban33.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

On the left there will be one big picture, on the right two on 50% (or 66/33 for example)

There are no problems with making two columns, and in the right two lines, but it does not work out so that the right pictures do not go beyond the height of the left.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Do you want the two columns to have equal height? Do you want them to have equal width? What happens on tablet? What happens on mobile?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Equal by height for all block, equal by width for right column

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the width of the image in the left column is overflowing its parent. Also there are margin that is preventing the left and right columns from collapsing

To prevent other elements from being affected

add a class name `left-col` to the first div with class name `col-md-6`

add a class name `righ-col` to the second div with class name `col-md-6`

style as follows

```
.left-col{
  padding-right:0;
  margin-right:0;
}
.right-col{
  padding-left:0;
  margin-lrft:0''
}
.col-md-6 img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

snippet below

[pen is here](http://codepen.io/repzeroworld/pen/rybxEE)